# Is there a more elegant way to write this CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

This works, but does any have a suggestion for a more simplified / elegant way to write this?:

```
if @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['mediaType'] is 'photo' and
  @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['econ_status'] is 'loaded' and
  @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['medium_status'] is 'loaded' and
  @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['thumb_status'] is 'loaded' and
  not @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['targetEventRecord']?
    @addMedia @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['targetEventRecord'], mid, @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['mediaType']
else if @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['mediaType'] is 'video' and
  @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['video_status'] is 'loaded' and
  not @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['targetEventRecord']?
    @addMedia @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['targetEventRecord'], mid, @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]['mediaType']
```

Comment: "Is there a more elegant way to write this CoffeeScript?" - sure, rewrite it in C. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! First, notice that `@mediaAddQueue[''+mid]` is repeated all over the place, you can replace that with a variable. Also, there's no need to access properties like `something['prop']` if the property has a valid identifier as a name; you can do `something.prop`. Changing those two things already cleans the code quite a bit:

```
media = @mediaAddQueue[mid]

if media.mediaType is 'photo' and
  media.econ_status is 'loaded' and
  media.medium_status is 'loaded' and
  media.thumb_status is 'loaded' and
  not media.targetEventRecord?
    @addMedia media.targetEventRecord, mid, media.mediaType
else if media.mediaType is 'video' and
  media.video_status is 'loaded' and
  not media.targetEventRecord?
    @addMedia media.targetEventRecord, mid, media.mediaType
```

Then, notice that the code inside both the `if` and the `else if` is the same. I think it would be great if you could give some meaningful name to the conditions so that the code becomes more self-documented and DRY. I don't know much about the context of this code, so i'll be guessing the variable names; try to use something that explains their meaning as clearly as possible:

```
media = @mediaAddQueue[mid]

isValidPhoto = media.mediaType is 'photo' and
  media.econ_status is 'loaded' and
  media.medium_status is 'loaded' and
  media.thumb_status is 'loaded' and
  not media.targetEventRecord?

isValidVideo = media.mediaType is 'video' and
  media.video_status is 'loaded' and
  not media.targetEventRecord?

if isValidPhoto or isValidVideo
  @addMedia media.targetEventRecord, mid, media.mediaType
```

Comment: promanow added his answer while i was writing mine. His recommendation about using functions to DRY up code is very useful, IMO. I tend to just use variables if the functionality is very local to some function... but if it needs to be used in different places, don't think twice: go for function! =D

Comment: That is right -- function is very rarely a **bad** idea. And JavaScript/CoffeeScript make them the very foundation of the language, feel encouraged to use them as often as possible ;)

Answer (score 4):

Sure is. There is always *something* that can be refactored.

**Temporary variables**

```
@mediaAddQueue[''+mid]
```

Is everywhere. Consider refactoring by introducing a temporary helper variable:

```
elem = @mediaAddQueue[''+mid]
```

The code will suddenly become more readable.

**Functions, functions, functions!**

I see you perform a specific type of check (I've assumed that we have the `elem` variable):

```
elem['econ_status'] is 'loaded' and
elem['medium_status'] is 'loaded' and
elem['thumb_status'] is 'loaded'
```

You could write a function that takes such `elem` (or whatever that object is) and performs this check, its arguments being the object, the value to compare and object's keys. This is very easy in Coffee thanks to splats.

```
##
# Check whether all obj's keys are set to value.
checkAllKeys = (obj, value, keys...) ->
    for k in keys
        if obj[k] != value
           return false

    return true
```

Now that previous code block would become:

```
checkAllKeys(elem, 'loaded', 'econ_status', 'medium_status', 'thumb_status')
```

If you know that you will check for 'loaded' value often, make yourself another function:

```
checkLoaded = (elem, keys...) ->
    checkAllKeys(elem, 'loaded', keys...)
```

If `'econ_status', 'medium_status', 'thumb_status'` keys are often checked together, then even one more function might be a good idea:

```
checkPhotoLoaded = (photo) ->
    checkLoaded(photo, 'econ_status', 'medium_status', 'thumb_status')
```

My rule for refactorings is that one should write a function for all stuff that repeats more than twice. CoffeeScript makes writing functions fun, and fast.

I hope this has been helpful.

Comment: The most elegant & functional answer by far ;})

Answer (score 0):

Going from the epidemian answer, I would still refactor it a bit to this:

```
media = @mediaAddQueue[mid]

typeValidationMap =
  'photo' : (m) ->
    m.econ_status is 'loaded' and
    m.medium_status is 'loaded' and
    m.thumb_status is 'loaded'
  'video' : (m) ->
    m.video_status is 'loaded'
  'default': () -> no

isValidMedia = (m) ->
  return no if m.targetEventRecord?
  validate = typeValidationMap[m.mediaType] or typeValidationMap.default
  validate m

if isValidMedia media
  @addMedia media.targetEventRecord, mid, media.mediaType
```

side note: I noticed you pass a always null targetEventRecord in that case